# Firebird shows question marks in a UTF-8 charset field

Tags: firebird, charset

I have a charset problem with Firebird. I have a database with 80+ tables that I started a few years ago and its default charset is NONE, but I set every VARCHAR field to UTF-8 (and also collation to UTF-8).
I've been using it for English and Hebrew with no problem, but now I have inputs with Russian/Ukrainian and the fields are being filled with question marks (??????). Both Firebird Maestro and Flame Robin show these question marks in the data. I'm using Firebird 2.5.8 if it helps.
From Stack Overflow answers I found that every field has it's own charset, so what am I missing?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], and double check if the problem doesn't happen at the point where the data is stored in the database (if you're storing those question marks, then of course your tools will show them). Also, depending on how you connect to the database, it may be necessary to specify an explicit connection character. Some older Firebird tools have never been changed to inspect the metadata of a column to use the right character set, so if you use connection character set, it might default to writing things with the wrong character set.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you missed connection charset. If it is NONE, data is put into fields as is so even if by chance sequence of bytes is valid for UTF-8, it may be meaningless. When you try to retrieve such broken data and display them - result is question signs that is a default substitute character for characters missed in target code page. AFAIK both Maestro and Flame Robin are ANSI applications so they can display only characters from current ANSI code page on Windows (I suspect it is Hebrew in your case). For displaying of full Unicode data you need something else.

So first of all you must check that data in the database is really in valid UTF-8 and Russian/Ukrainian characters have right encoding. You can do that by casting it to charset OCTETS and inspecting result in hex. If data in the database is ok - problem is on displaying application's side.

Comment: In theory, with connection character set NONE, tools should use the character set of the individual column to write and read the data with the right character set, in practice some of the older tools don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you user1396... and Mark Rotteveel (and sorry for the delay).

the problem was not in the Connection, but you both sent me to the right place to look for - if the data written in the DB is really UTF-8.

by working with a "difficult" language like Hebrew, i thought every other language should be fine to work with.

i use Delphi and the problem was that the data really didn't save as UTF8 even tho i know Delphi strings are Unicode.
the solution was to save the data as WideString instead of String that to my surprise works different with Unicode\UTF8...

Thanks you guys!

Comment: The Delphi `UnicodeString` is UTF-16 not UTF-8. It is both documented and obvious, because `sizeof(WideChar)` is not equal to `sizeof(AnsiChar)`. Unicode is not same as UTF-8, those are orthogonal concepts. Remember, there is no such thoing as just a text!  https://blog.codinghorror.com/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text/